# Asymmetrical stress tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible that after transformating (primary) SYMMETRICAL stress tensor to a particular fault plane (with strike/dip/rake) to get ASYMMETRICAL (secondary) stress tensor?

Answer (score 1):

In classical elasticity (so excluding concentrated couples, like in Cosserat solids or so), the stress tensor has to be symmetric for equilibrium to hold (an argument that dates back to Cauchy himself: this is also why there only 3 Cauchy'S equilibrium equations, for each translation, as rotations are automatically satisfied by imposing symmetry to the stress tensor).

If say $\tau_{xy}$ (so shear strain on a plane normal to $x$, in direction $y$) were different from $ \tau_{yx} $, no rotational equilibrium could be achieved.

As equilibrium cannot depend on the coordinate system used to write a matrix down, symmetry has to be preserved for elasticity to be a sound theory.

If you showed us your initial stress matrix and the rotatins you applied, maybe I could help further.